# Join two tables on multiple columns with OR and label

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as shown here:

| orderID | customerID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 |
| 2 | 1002 |
| 3 | 1003 |
| 4 | 1003 |

and the other one is like:

| userID | Service1FirstOrderID | Serice2FirstOrderID | Service3FirstOrderID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | null | 1 | null |
| 1002 | 2 | null | null |
| 1003 | 3 | null | 4 |

Now I want to join these two tables so that I can get every customer id with `ServiceID` that have been purchased.

| UserID | Service |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2 |
| 1002 | 1 |
| 1003 | 1 |
| 1003 | 3 |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you really using? MySQL (x)or MySQL? Only tag the one you're really using, not more than that. [Edit] the question to do so.

Comment: You're right. I am using SQL Server

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain the logic behind the result.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is a join at all. It seems to be purely a conditional unpivot of the second table, you can do this with `CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1 WHERE Service1FirstOrderID IS NOT NULL UNION ALL SELECT 2 WHERE Service2FirstOrderID IS NOT NULL...` see for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df2504f45293998afdfcc1b66b6976be. Although why you have such a bad denormalized structure in the first place is a different question

Comment: That's not gonna work because other there are some other columns and conditions that has been applied to the first table and I should count the customerID so I have to join these two tables so that I can count customer for each service

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to join on an `IN`

> ```
> SELECT
>   so.userID
> , CASE 
>   WHEN o.OrderID = so.Service1FirstOrderID THEN 1
>   WHEN o.OrderID = so.Service2FirstOrderID THEN 2
>   WHEN o.OrderID = so.Service3FirstOrderID THEN 3
>   END AS Service
> FROM Orders o
> INNER JOIN ServiceOrders so
>   ON so.userID = o.customerID
>  AND o.OrderID IN (so.Service1FirstOrderID, so.Service2FirstOrderID, so.Service3FirstOrderID)
> ORDER BY o.customerID;
> ```

| userID | Service |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2 |
| 1002 | 1 |
| 1003 | 1 |
| 1003 | 3 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6fee67fe72ef389bf1ec6df4f2fd6fd)*

Answer (score 0):

You have a heavily denormalized table structure, but it appears that this is not a join at all.

It seems to be purely a conditional unpivot of the second table, which you can do with `CROSS APPLY`

```sql
SELECT
  t2.UserId,
  v.*
FROM table2 t2
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 1
    WHERE Service1FirstOrderID IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    WHERE Service2FirstOrderID IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    WHERE Service3FirstOrderID IS NOT NULL
) v(Service);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df2504f45293998afdfcc1b66b6976be)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CTE.

```sql
;WITH CTE_ServiceOrder as
(
SELECT UserId, 1 AS ServiceId, Service1FirstOrderID as orderId
from ServiceOrders
where Service1FirstOrderId is not null
union all
SELECT UserId, 2,  Service2FirstOrderID as orderId
from ServiceOrders
where Service2FirstOrderId is not null
union all
SELECT UserId, 3, Service3FirstOrderID as orderId
from ServiceOrders
where Service3FirstOrderId is not null
)
SELECT o.customerID, s.ServiceId FROM CTE_ServiceOrder as s
INNER JOIN Orders as o
on o.orderID = s.orderid
order by o.customerID
```

Thanks to @Lukstorms for create script.

You can refer to the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=86987cc056095a24a9613a27d4c6225c)